# Join between View and table via JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

There is a table called **asset** and there is a view made of two table **asset** and **assetprice** called **assetDetail**.

There is a one to one relation between **asset** and **assetDetail**.

Asset Table fields are:{asset_id(pk),name,notes}

AssetDetail view fields are: {asset_id,price,buy_date}

```
Public class Asset{

..
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "asset_id")
AssetDetail assetDetail;
...
}

Public class AssetDetail{

..
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "asset_id")
Asset asset;
...
}
```

Please tell is this OK?

Comment: why don't you try it?

Comment: I tried it is making recursive calls...

Comment: I don't have any problem with your example. Hibernate 5.0.9.Final.